# Faking a pass method when building an array

Tags: ruby, array

Ruby doesn't have a pass method to 'do nothing' the way Python does - if I want a ternary statement to do something on true, but nothing on false (as in the code below). Is it bad practice in Ruby to fake it this way?

```
beverage_links = []

beverage_info.each do |bvg|
   self.is_menu_item?(bvg) ? beverage_links << bvg["href"] : "pass"
end
```

Comment: What's wrong with a normal conditional expression? `beverage_links << bvg["href"] if self.is_menu_item?(bvg)`. Note also: `self` is the implicit receiver, no need to explicitly state it. Predicate methods are indicated by a question mark in their name, there is no need to name them `is_something`. And the whole thing can be better expressed using higher-level iteration methods: `beverage_info.select(&method(:menu_item?)).map {|bvg| bvg['href'] }`.

Comment: @200_success, this is real code from a gem I'm working on to get drink information from Starbucks' website (https://github.com/RSid/starbucksstats). I just cut out the parts of the class that were irrelevant to my question. I can add in more context if that's preferred, but it wouldn't have any impact on what I'm asking.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, I just preferred getting it onto one line to having an if statement nested in there. Your example with the iteration methods is much cleaner though, thanks.

Comment: `if` is *not* a statement in Ruby. It's an *expression*. In fact, in Ruby, *everything* is an expression, there *are no* statements. In C, the conditional operator is needed because `if` is a statement, and the operators are expressions, so when you need an expression, you cannot use `if`, you *have* to use the conditional operator. But in Ruby, you *never* need the conditional operator, you can *always* use `if`, because it is *already* an expression. The conditional has weird precedence which will sometimes force you to add parentheses, which the `if` expression doesn't have.

Comment: Huh, cool. I'm relatively new to Ruby (I spend most of my time in C#), so I'm still learning stuff like this.

Comment: Please add more context. We will likely need to change more than just these few lines of code in isolation.

Comment: @200_success I have an answer for this question but you have closed it, even though it does not appear to need more context

Comment: @DevonParsons Reopened.

Comment: I encourage you to post all of `starbucksstats.rb` as a separate question. The use of a `module` is questionable, and there is a lot of repeated code.

Comment: I don't regard the current code as review-ready. It's still in progress and I'm still learning. It'd probably make more sense to post it once I've refactored it myself and taken that as far as I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What it looks like you really want is:

```
beverage_links = beverage_info.select{|bvg| self.is_menu_item?(bvg)}.map{|bvg|bvg["href"]}
```

This might be a bit confusing, so to break it down

```
beverage_info.select { |bvg| self.is_menu_item?( bvg ) }
```

This returns an array of items in `beverage_info` that return `true`* for `is_menu_item?`

```
  .map { |bvg| bvg["href"] }
```

This translates each of the items in the array returned in the previous into their `"href"` value. Finally you assign that to beverage_links.

If `beverage_info` is an array of beverages, I recommend you rename it to `beverages`. It is obvious that if you have a beverage, you have the info of that beverage.

If beverages are a custom class, give it the method `is_menu_item?` because nothing else will use that (unless you have, say, burgers that are also menu items. In that case, both `Beverages` and `Burgers` should extend some `Food` class that has the `is_menu_item?` method).  The way you have it now, it doesn't look like you need to be using the `self` keyword, but it's hard to tell without context.

---

* Actually, it returns all items that return ANYTHING that isn't `false` or `nil` for `is_menu_item?`

Comment: Thanks! This was a helpful and complete answer. 

I'm guessing the general consensus is that faking a 'pass' is, in addition to being the wrong solution here, usually a sign of not writing ruby-idiomatic code and to be re-examined.